# Removal of Role PostgreSQL Failed - cache lookup failed for database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

This is my first time using PostgreSQL for production.

I made a database `blog_production` with username `blog_production` and generated password from gemfile `capistrano-postgresql`. Once it is generated, I tried to delete database `blog_production` with this command from terminal:

`$ sudo -u postgres dropdb blog_production`

After that I tried to delete user `blog_production` with this command:

`$ sudo -u postgres droprole blog_production`

And it returned `dropuser: removal of role "blog_production" failed: ERROR:  cache lookup failed for database 16417`

1.) Why is this happening? 
2.) I also tried to delete from `psql` using `DELETE FROM pg_roles WHERE rolname='blog_production'` but it returned the same error (cache lookup failed)
3.) How do I solve this problem?

Thank you.

**Additional Information** 
PostgreSQL Version
`PostgreSQL 9.1.15 on x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.6.3-1ubuntu5) 4.6.3, 64-bit
(1 row)`

`select * from pg_shdepend where dbid = 16417;`

```
 dbid  | classid | objid | objsubid | refclassid | refobjid | deptype 
-------+---------+-------+----------+------------+----------+---------
 16417 |    1259 | 16419 |        0 |       1260 |    16418 | o
 16417 |    1259 | 16426 |        0 |       1260 |    16418 | o
 16417 |    1259 | 16428 |        0 |       1260 |    16418 | o
(3 rows)
```

`select * from pg_database where oid = 16417;`

```
 datname | datdba | encoding | datcollate | datctype | datistemplate | datallowconn | datconnlimit | datlastsysoid | datfrozenxid | dattablespace | datacl 
---------+--------+----------+------------+----------+---------------+--------------+--------------+---------------+--------------+---------------+--------
(0 rows)
```

`select * from pg_authid where rolname = 'blog_production'`

```
     rolname     | rolsuper | rolinherit | rolcreaterole | rolcreatedb | rolcatupdate | rolcanlogin | rolreplication | rolconnlimit |             rolpassword             | rolvaliduntil 
-----------------+----------+------------+---------------+-------------+--------------+-------------+----------------+--------------+-------------------------------------+---------------
 blog_production | f        | t          | f             | f           | f            | t           | f              |           -1 | md5d4d2f8789ab11ba2bd019bab8be627e6 | 
(1 row)
```

Comment: You can *probably* solve the problem by connecting with psql, then executing the SQL statement `drop role blog_production;`.

Comment: @Mike Sherrill 'Cat Recall
I've tried that and it returns the same error `ERROR:  cache lookup failed for database 16417`

Comment: How long ago was your last backup?

Comment: I didn't do any backup. I just make a new dummy rails app to test if I can deploy it successfully to Azure. I just want to delete blog_production, because I want to redeploy it from scratch. @Mike Sherrill 'Cat Recall

Comment: Do you control the production server? Or is it part of a service like Heroku?

Comment: Yes I control the VPS (Ubuntu 14, PostgreSQL 9.1). It's not part of a service like Heroku, it's like Linode VPS. I have root access.

Comment: This kind of error usually indicates some kind of database corruption. Although it might or might not be repairable, I think your best way forward is to nuke it, install PostgreSQL 9.4 (the current version) if that's possible, and init the PostgreSQL data directory all over again. The main goal would be the init. That would give you a clean data directory and system catalogs.

Comment: What do you mean by nuking postgreSQL? Is it uninstall the postgreSQL? I will try to uninstall and reinstall again, see if the error is coming back or not. Thanks

Comment: What's the exact PostgreSQL version here? `SELECT version()` please. Also, how was PostgreSQL installed? (While corruption is possible here, a simple bug may also be the explanation). @abrahamks, I suspect that simply restarting PostgreSQL will resolve this, but I'd like to know how it happened in the first place; it isn't supposed to, obviously.

Comment: I meant to remove PostgreSQL and kill the data directory. But listen to Craig Ringer. He knows a lot more about PostgreSQL than I do. (He knows more about PostgreSQL that 99.9% of SO.)

Comment: @CraigRinger
I installed PostgreSQL with this command `sudo apt-get -y install postgresql postgresql-contrib libpq-dev`

I tried to restart with `sudo -u postgres service postgresql restart` and when I tried to delete it, it keeps return the same error (cache lookup failed)

Comment: @abrahamks Have you ever run the db with the `fsync` option set to `off`? I've tried a variety of things and can't reproduce this locally. Can you post the output of: `select * from pg_shdepend where dbid = 16417`, `select * from pg_database where oid = 16417` and `select * from pg_authid where rolname = 'blog_production'` ?

Comment: @CraigRinger I didnt do any `fsync` option before. I have added the output from those commands in my post. Thanks

Answer (score 4):

Somehow the `DROP database;` didn't drop the shared dependencies correctly. PostgreSQL still thinks that your user owns three tables in the database you dropped.

Needless to say this should not happen; it's almost certainly a bug, though I don't know how we'd even begin tracking it down unless you know *exactly* what commands you ran etc to get to this point, right from creating the DB.

---

If the PostgreSQL install's data isn't very big and if you can share the contents, can I get you to stop the database server and make a tarball of the whole database directory, then send it to me? I'd like to see if I can tell what happened to get you to this point.

Send a dropbox link to craig@2ndquadrant.com . Just:

```
sudo service postgresql stop

sudo tar cpjf ~abrahamks/abrahamks-postgres.tar.gz \
   /var/lib/postgresql/9.1/main \
   /etc/postgresql/9.1/main \
   /var/log/postgresql/postgresql-9.1-main-*.
   /usr/lib/postgresql/9.1

sudo chown abrahamks ~abrahamks/abrahamks-postgres.tar.gz
```

and upload `abrahamks-postgres.tar.gz` from your home folder.

Replace `abrahamks` with your username on your system. You might need to adjust the paths above if I'm misremembering where the PostgreSQL data lives on Debian-derived systems.

Note that this contains **all your databases** not just the one that was an issue, and it also contains your PostgreSQL user accounts.

(If you're going to send me a copy, do so *before* continuing):

---

Anyway, since the database is dropped, it is safe to manually remove the dependencies that should've been removed by `DROP DATABASE`:

```
DELETE FROM pg_shdepend WHERE dbid = 16417
```

It should then be possible to `DROP USER blog_production;`

Comment: In PG 14 I hit this after experimenting with calling `DELETE FROM pg_database WHERE ...`. No idea if that is a bug or by-design. I haven't tried it in PG 15 yet.